# Copy data from another workbook to an active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change my code so that the copied selection from another file pastes to an active cell in an open Workbook:

---

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
`Dim FiletoOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FiletoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx),*xlsx*")

If FiletoOpen <> False Then

Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FiletoOpen)
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D1:D100").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
OpenBook.Close False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

---

I tried to change this row:
`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

to
`ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Also, I tried to define a range like in this example:
`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

And this works. I don't want, however to copy to the range, but instead to an active selected cell in my open workbook.

Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveCell` is a property of the application, not a sheet which is why you can not access it as originally written. I'm experimenting with your code and it looks like when a sheet is opened, `ActiveCell` becomes `A1` of the opened sheet.

So how about something like:

```
' ++ make a note of current active cell before opening file
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveCell


FiletoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx),*xlsx*")

...

'-- ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'++ Copy to saved range
r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Complete sub:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Get_Data_From_File()
Dim FiletoOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' ++ make a note of current active cell before opening file
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveCell


FiletoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx),*xlsx*")

If FiletoOpen <> False Then

Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FiletoOpen)
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D1:D100").Copy

'-- ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'++ Copy to saved range
r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

OpenBook.Close False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: would that also be possible to pick a specific range, like in a message window? or would that be another code?

Comment: Thanks @LittleCode - if youre happy with taht could you upvote/select as solution? Would be appreciated ... to enter a range you can use `Application.InputBox` method - they even have an example on the microsoft docs : `This example prompts the user to select a cell on Sheet1. The example uses the Type argument to ensure that the return value is a valid cell reference (a Range object).

VB

Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
Set myCell = Application.InputBox( _ 
    prompt:="Select a cell", Type:=8)`

Comment: ^ formatting not great - check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox